# How to resolve conflict between struct and module names?

Tags: swift

I have module Data. Inside Data I have struct X.

```swift
struct X<T> {
   var t: T
}
```

And class Y with typealias X inside

```swift
class Y {
  typealias X = X<Int>
}
```

The last one code sample has compilation error:

> Type alias 'X' references itself

Ok, compiler can't understand that X is struct defined outside Y, it think that is typealias in Y. I tried to concretize X by adding container module name.

```swift
class Y {
  typealias X = Data.X<Int>
}
```

But as the result, compiler gives other error:

> 'X' is not a member type of 'Data'

How it possible? X is member of Data. After jump to definition of Data I found that Data is struct in Foundation.

I can't remove `import Foundation` because my code uses UUID and Date. Is it possible to resolve this conflict without creating unnecessary type alias for Data.X?

---

(30.10.19)
After some confusions around of the current question I did the following experiment. I did it to avoid any intersections with standart Swift libraries. Hope that this note will do problem described in my question clearer.

- Create project A with Src.swift

```swift
public struct B {}
```

- Create project B with Src.swift

```swift
public struct X { }
```

- Create project C with Src.swift

```swift
import A
import B

struct X { }
typealias Y = B.X
```

After compiling A, B, C I have the same error (from semantic point of view).

> 'X' is not a member type of 'B'

Comment: Your module name is totally wrong. How will compiler differentiate between your module and native one?

Comment: @Karman "How?" It is question about politics. As alternative, compiler could give higher priority to name  of module than struct name (even if it is native). In this politics I can concretize Foundation.Data.

Comment: Actually it has many problems to use same name. Leave compiler, no new developer will know if this is a module `Data` or Foundation `Data`. It is not realistic. Naming conventions don't allow this.

Comment: @Kamran It is not about naming convention, it is about compilation error that looks like semantic error. Module and type can't be used in the same context, I can't imagine how new developer can confuse module and type. But it isn't clear for compiler and I'm finding way how to do it clear.

Comment: @Kamran I checked that I can resolve name conflict of structs so easy. I created modules A and B with code `public class Data { }` in both. I created module C with code `print(A.Data.self); print(C.Data.self); print(Foundation.Data.self)`. All modules was compiled succeed. Which Data is using is clear for compiler and for new developer. And solution that i trying to find can be evident for new developer. But as I see no solution exists. Is it true?

Comment: small fix to previous comment: *And possibly that potential solution provides evidently clear syntax expression (for new developer).

Comment: As `Data` is declared inside module `A`, `B` or `C` so you can definitely use `A.Data`, `B.Data` with no issues because here `Data` is not a module and compiler has no issues if you are using `Data` explicitly with their module names. But what you can't do is the same name of the module as `Data` or any `Swift` framework.

Comment: @Kamra I updated my question with example that doesn't contains conflict with any standard Swift library. I hope that this example highlights what I was asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following scenario resolves name conflict between struct and module for second case which contains **A**, **B**, **C** projects. This solution is based on rule that we can edit only **C** project. Because **C** is our client of hypothetically third-party unchangeable modules **A** and **B**.

1. Add new Swift file into **C** project with code below

```swift
import struct A.B
typealias StructB = B
```

2. Change code in Src.swift to the following

```swift
import B
let structB: StructB? = nil

struct X { }
typealias Y = B.X
```

Result is succeeded compilation without error:

> 'X' is not a member type of 'B'

And we can use struct **B** from module **A** and struct from module **B** in single file. The name conflict has been resolved.

---

The second one scenario resolves conflict in the first case with **Data**.

1. Replace

```swift
import Foundation
```

with

```swift
import struct Foundation.Date
import struct Foundation.UUID
```

2. Be sure that Foundation isn't imported in module level. In my case I removed `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` from Data.h. And replaced `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` with `extern` to do Data.h compilable.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `typealias` name from `X` to `x`, i.e.

```
class Y {
    typealias x = X<Int>
}
```

Also, `Data` is a predefined type in *Swift*. That's why you're getting **'X' is not a member type of 'Data'** error.

Comment: No, your answer avoid the question, not solve. The same names are necessary as base of names conflict problem. If all names will unique - name conflicts problem will be missing in programming world. But it is not, and almost all languages has mechanisms to solve this problem (and swift too). Your answer will be correct if it will say 'swift doesn't provide mechanism to solve this names conflict'.

Comment: Can you please tell how come swift allow same names for different variables? Because the way you're using it is not recommended or resolved in any programming language.

Comment: Nothing about variables in my question, it is about Modules, Structs and Typealiases. It is offtopic, but just for example: C++ provides ability to declare two variables with same names in different namespaces. And I checked that swift also provides this ability. I created A and B modules with `public let x: Int = ...` and C with `print(A.x); print(B.x)` All three modules was compiled succeeded. But question isn't about variables.

Comment: My problem isn't actual in C++, C#, F#, Java, Scala, OCaml... In all those languages compilers can parse 'what is it namespace or type?' from the context. It is first time when I found situation where type hides namespace. It isn't common namespaces concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace. It is marginal. Also my question isn't about languages comparison. I asked about concrete problem that I found while programming in Swift.

Comment: OCaml should be missing in my list. It has specific modules system. But this problem can be solved in ocaml by bound module name to another name.

Comment: I updated my question with example that doesn't contains conflict with any standard Swift library. I hope that this example highlights what I was asking about.